# HTML Page Not Showing Python Flask Data Fetched From SQL Server

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, frontend

So I have a Python flask app I want to deploy. My goal is to fetch data from a SQL server, and relay that information on the frontend using HTML in a tabular format.

This is my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import pyodbc

app = Flask(__name__)

# Database credentials
server = 'server'
database = 'database'
username = 'user'
password = 'password'
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

# Connection string
connection_string = f"DRIVER={{{driver}}};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}"

@app.route('/')
def show_results():
    try:
        # Connect to the database
        print("Connecting to the database...")
        conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
        print("Connected successfully.")

        # Execute the provided SQL query
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = """
        WITH RankedDocs AS (
            SELECT
                td.HWANumber,
                td.GroupNumber,
                a.SerialNumber,
                d.DocUploadData,
                d.DocName,
                d.DocDate,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY td.HWANumber ORDER BY d.DocDate DESC) AS rn
            FROM documents d
            LEFT JOIN assets a
                ON d.EntityTypeID = a.AssetID
            LEFT JOIN TankDetails td
                ON a.AssetID = td.LQDB_TankId
            WHERE td.HWANumber = 'HWA-011641'
        )
        SELECT 
            HWANumber,
            GroupNumber,
            SerialNumber,
            DocUploadData,
            DocName,
            DocDate
        FROM RankedDocs
        WHERE rn = 1
        """
        print("Executing SQL query...")
        cursor.execute(query)

        # Fetch results
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        print("Fetched data:", rows)

        # Close the connection when done
        conn.close()
        print("Database connection closed.")

        return render_template('index.html', rows=rows)

    except pyodbc.Error as ex:
        print("An error occurred:", ex)
        return f"An error occurred: {ex}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting the `Flask app...")
    app.run(debug=True)`
```

As you can see, it pulls data from my sql server and returns it as a json. Now what I hope to do is show this data into a table using HTML. I created an index.html file under templates. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SQL Query Results</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        h1 {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>SQL Query Results</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>HWANumber</th>
                <th>GroupNumber</th>
                <th>SerialNumber</th>
                <th>DocUploadData</th>
                <th>DocName</th>
                <th>DocDate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row in rows %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row.HWANumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.GroupNumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.SerialNumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.DocUploadData }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.DocName }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.DocDate }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the console shows that the queries are working and the data is being fetched. No 404 errors are popping up. But for some reason, when I open the webpage using the localhost link provided by the app, the webpage is showing up blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "it pulls data from my sql server and returns it as a json" no it returns it as a templated HTML string. "the webpage is showing up blank" you should *at least* be seeing the "SQL Query Results" H1 tag...are you? Or is it totally blank? Are there any errors in the terminal where you're running your flask server after you make the request (especially since you are *only* catching database errors)? What happens if you return `json.dumps(rows)` instead of `render_template(...)`? Do you see the data in JSON form in your browser?

Comment: it shows up completely blank. Not even H2 tag. Now when I created a fetch /data that shows me the reults in json format and plug that in the localhost url, then I see all the sql data results

Comment: Then the problem is most likely in the template rendering, again are there any Python errors in the terminal?

Comment: No. the fetched data is showing up in my terminal and all my error tests are successfull

Comment: you have any reason for not using flask sqlalchemy ?

Comment: Im new to all of this so I did not know about sqlalchemy